# Resource not found but is found

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I use the following partial code to add a textblock to a DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
FrameworkElementFactory tb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
tb.SetValue(TextBlock.IsHitTestVisibleProperty, false);
tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.DataContextProperty, new Binding("doorparameters[" + pid.ToString() + "]"));
tb.SetResourceReference(TextBlock.StyleProperty, "ParameterTextBlockStyle");
```

It all works fine but when I run in debug mode the output window shows the folllowing error:

> System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ParameterTextBlockStyle'

The "ParameterTextBlockStyle" is defined in the resources of the datagrid, not the Window resources. The odd part is it doesn't matter which resource the style is defined in, I always get this message.

Can this error be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
FrameworkElementFactory tb = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
tb.SetValue(TextBlock.IsHitTestVisibleProperty, false);
tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.DataContextProperty, new Binding("doorparameters[" + pid.ToString() + "]"));
tb.SetResourceReference(TextBlock.StyleProperty, (Style)dataGrid.FindResource("ParameterTextBlockStyle"));
```

Comment: The error is now: 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='System.Windows.Style'; ResourceKey.HashCode='20'; ResourceKey.Type='System.Windows.Style''

Comment: Can you try, `Style tmpStyle = (Style)dataGrid.FindResource("ParameterTextBlockStyle");` only this line  and debug it. If tmpStyle is NULL or throws an exception, we can maybe try something else.

Answer (score 0):

`SetResourceReference` is the equivalent of `DynamicResource`, and IIRC the `DataGridTemplateColumn` uses some hacks to render itself. *(Sorry, at this point I just don't recall what it is exactly).*

You could try the equivalent of `StaticResource` instead, which should be more reliable because it doesn't have to find the style through walking the logical tree:

```
tb.SetValue(FrameworkElement.StylePropertyProperty,
            dataGrid.FindResource("ParameterTextBlockStyle"));
```

Comment: tb is class FrameworkElementFactory which doesn't expose the Style property directly.

Comment: @Paul Sorry, of course, I didn't notice. I've updated my answer.